# My QGIS says "PyQGIS couldn't be loaded"

Tags: qgis, python

My QGIS (Version 3.2.3-Bonn 'Bonn', 9b17680) says:

> PyQGIS konnte nicht geladen werden. Die Python-Unterstützung wird
>   abgeschaltet.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'
>
> Python-Version:
>   3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19)  [GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
>
> QGIS-Version:
>   3.2.3-Bonn 'Bonn', 9b17680
>
> Python-Pfad: ['/usr/share/qgis/python',
>   '/home/christoph/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python',
>   '/home/christoph/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins',
>   '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins',
>   '/home/christoph/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python',
>   '/home/christoph/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip',
>   '/home/christoph/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
>   '/home/christoph/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
>   '/home/christoph/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Could it be, it's not finding the right Python?